# Mouse randomly stops working,

Tags: mouse

the mouse still lights up, but it seems to constantly play the windows device disconnect sound. I keep having to delete my mouse driver and restarting my pc, which fixes it, but issue comes back later, completely at random

Comment: Try a different mouse.

Comment: A mouse is too cheap to be repaired.

Comment: @Tetsujin i have, same issue with it not working until i reinstall the driver, then the issue occurring all over again later

Comment: Then the port itself may be intermittent - try another port.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried every port, issue persists. I'd also like to mention that this started happening randomly, after updating windows.

Comment: You should add all salient information to your question, to save duplication of effort.